# How can I intentionally leak an object, so that it will never ever be garbage collected?

Tags: python

Here's a weird problem: I want to intentionally leak a Python object, and all the objects it references. I want them to become immortal. And most importantly, I want to guarantee that their finalizer / `__del__` methods will never run. (The motivation is related to an exotic issue around `fork`-safety that I won't go into here. `fork` is the worst, but we're stuck with it.)

What's the simplest way to reliably do that? I can save a reference to it in a module global variable, but the interpreter can and might garbage collect module-globals when the program is shutting down, right?

I *think* it would work to spawn a thread with `daemon=True` that holds a reference to the object on its stack and just sleeps forever, but this is pretty weird and seeing this random thread will confuse people using debuggers.

On CPython, I could use a `ctypes` hack to manually increment the object's reference count, but that won't work on other interpreters like PyPy.

What's the most portable, reliable, cleanest way to accomplish this ugly goal?

(I only care about Python 3.5+, in case that affects anything.)

Comment: I can save a reference to it in a module global variable, but the interpreter can and might garbage collect module-globals when the program is shutting down, right? <- What's wrong with collecting the object on program shutdown?

Comment: @timgeb The object might have a `__del__` method that has some side-effects, and I want to make sure those side-effects don't happen. If they happen at program shutdown, that's still bad.

Comment: Then override/monkey-patch `__del__` to do nothing.

Comment: That's a clever idea, but in my case it's impractical for a bunch of reasons. (It's a whole object graph, not just one object; some of the types I'd need to monkeypatch are built-in and thus can't be monkeypatched; and even if I monkeypatching worked it would affect all instances of the type, not just the ones I want to make immortal.)

Comment: Hm. You could disable the garbage collector alltogether. I don't know whether this is feasible or even applies to program shutdown.

Comment: Don't let Python ever do its final cleanup; use `os._exit()` instead (`sys._exit()` on older versions).  To do as much cleanup as possible, call this in an `atexit` handler registered as early as possible (before any other module imports are done).  There *will* be side-effects to this.

Comment: You could hack at the refcount if you're on CPython, and if you're on PyPy simply storing it somewhere like in the ``sys`` module should be enough.